# Undefined method for Class error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Invitations controller I call on a method in my model:

```
if abc.nil?
 generate_username
end
```

The method is included in the Invitation model file:

```
def generate_username
  self.username = rand(10000000..99999999).to_s
  while Invitation.where( "lower(username) = ?", username.downcase ).first
    self.username = rand(10000000..99999999).to_s
  end
end
```

And in my Seeds file I have the line:

```
10.times do |n|
  ...
  user = User.first
  username = Invitation.generate_username
  ...
  user.active_relationships.create!( ...,
                                     username: username,
                                     ...)
end
```

Upon seeding I get the error below, referring to the `username =` line. Does anyone have an idea why this is the case and what I can do about it?

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `generate_username' for #<Class:0x00000009a2ab80>
```

Comment: Your `generate_username` is an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: Are you sure you have not defined inside the controller any method `generate_username` ? If you have the method inside the  model, you should get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an instance method, but you're trying to call it on a class. Use the method properly.

```
10.times do |n|
  ...
  user.generate_username
  ...
  user.active_relationships.create!( ...,
                                     username: user.username,
                                     ...)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I simplified the situation a bit too much in my post and therefore made some minor changes to it. The reason is, while `user` is in the `User` model, `generate_username` applies to an invitation, which is in the `Invitation` model. Thus username is the username for a guest user, who is not in the User table but in the Invitation table. Hence, `user.generate_username` then doesn't make sense since the username is meant for the guest for which there is no instance yet (the instance is created in the last line). Tried `username: self.generate_username` but also `undefined method`.

Comment: @Nick: yeah, get your objects straight and call the method on the right object. :)

Comment: I think in my situation in the seeds file, the object doesn't exist yet. The object/instance is created on the line `user.active_relationships.create!`. So I have no instance to call `generate_username` on. Or do you mean I should first execute the `user.active_relationships.create!` line without `username` and after that apply the `generate_username` method on the created instance?

Comment: @Nick: yep, that should work. Don't forget to save the object after.

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to have worked:: `@guest = user.active_relationships.create!( ...,...)` without username, and then: `@guest.update_attributes(username: @guest.generate_username)`